# Incrementing enum values by a fixed number in C

Tags: c, enums

Is it possible to increment the values of fields of an enum by a fixed number?

Say if I have an enum

```
typedef enum {
    VAL_A,
    VAL_B,
    VAL_C
}ENUM_X;
```

I want to define the enum in such a way that the values may increment by a fixed number (other than 1 which is default).  This would result in me having (let's say number is 4)

```
VAL_A = 4; VAL_B = 8; VAL_C = 12;
```

Also if the above answer is true, and there is any such mechanism, is it possible to make the values increment sequentially?

Say I've the same enum redefined as

```
typedef enum {
    #ifdef A
    VAL_A,
    #endif

    #ifdef B
    VAL_B,
    #endif

    #ifdef C
    VAL_C,
    #endif

    VAL_END
}ENUM_X;
```

And if for the above enum I define A and C, I should get

```
VAL_A = 4; VAL_C = 8;
```

But if I define only B and C, I should get

```
VAL_B = 4; VAL_C = 8;
```

And if I define all A, B and C, I should get

```
VAL_A = 4; VAL_B = 8; VAL_C = 12;
```

Comment: If we think of a way to do this, it would be more complicated than writing out the numbers yourself.

Comment: C doesn't have custom stepping of enumeration values. It's either plus one, or whatever value you explicitly set it to.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no such support in the language.

You might be able to do something more or less horrible using macros of course. I think the whole "automatically" part is troublesome, but people can come up with the most troublesome preprocessor constructs when motivated enough.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are very similar to `#define`. One of the advantage is that they make code readable. Instead of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) spread across the code, It's better to have a name for the number.

For the compiler, it will just replace the name with the associated number during it's operation.

There isn't any such option to "auto-increment" by fixed number, but you can follow this approach:

```
#define INCREMENT_ENUM_BY_NUM    4

typedef enum {
    VAL_A = 0 + INCREMENT_ENUM_BY_NUM,
    VAL_B = VAL_A + INCREMENT_ENUM_BY_NUM,
    VAL_C = VAL_B + INCREMENT_ENUM_BY_NUM,
}ENUM_X;
```

This is useful if your enum values are change frequently. But as with your second part with `#ifdef`, this won't be feasible as you have to change the code every time.

We had a case where some enums were changed as per customer requirement. So change those enums, build, and deliver. There, this approach was useful.
But in general, this is better:

```
typedef enum {
    VAL_A = 4,
    VAL_B = 8,
    VAL_C = 12
}ENUM_X;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. This will work even if only one of the 3 enums is defined.

```
#define INCREMENT_VALUE 4
#define VALUE 4
#define VALTEMP 4

#define INCR_OPERATION   \
    #undef VALTEMP  \
    #define VALTEMP VALUE \
    #undef VALUE \
    #define VALUE (VALTEMP+ INCREMENT_VALUE) \


typedef enum {
    #ifdef A
    VAL_A = VALUE,
    INCR_OPERATION
    #endif

    #ifdef B
    VAL_B = VALUE,
    INCR_OPERATION
    #endif

    #ifdef C
    VAL_C = VALUE,
    INCR_OPERATION
    #endif

    VAL_END = VALUE
}ENUM_X;
```